# Certain simple geometry animations

Tags: math-software

[image]

Asked to draw a quadrilateral with sides 3, 4, 5 and 6, one might create what's shown above, using the tools available in, say geogebra. A moment's reflection indicates that the requirement would be met if CD 'connected to' AD to make this a concave figure.

I have been searching for software that would enable its user to move BC and AC in such a way that remained attached to AB yet CD's length was a constant four.

[Instrumenpoche](https://instrumenpoche.sesamath.net/wiki/) seems a possibility; however, my French in poor. I would be willing to put in the effort if it appeared that it might be able to do this.

Incidentally, this is not a graphing problem, and I haven't been able to make geogebra do it.

Comment: The [r/geogebra subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/geogebra/) may be a better place for this question. It's the "official" community for help with the GeoGebra software.

Comment: Is something like [this](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/qu2adnd5) what you have in mind? I've set it so that C,D are fixed and the lengths of AB, BC, CD, AD remain fixed; this leaves one degree of freedom left which I've given to A.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Thanks. Something like that, yes, except that the lengths of all four sides must be fixed.

Comment: @Bill the sides AB, BC, CD, AD do have fixed length in the above. (That said, I seem to have set them as 4,5,4,3 respectively. So AB should be 6 instead.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: Something odd is happening: I have just visited the drawing once again; I can move vertex D so that the length of CD varies over a wide range.

Comment: I see what you mean. If you ignore that and focus on A instead it works fine, but that’s not ideal. In any case, though, there’s actually already Geogebra applets out there for four-bar linkages. See for instance: https://www.geogebra.org/m/BueCG9ch. (There’s a few others if that isn’t to your taste.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: I'm glad you see what I mean!

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat like in this sketch?

[image]

Ignore the given circle through D.

Line or link CD including end points remains fixed in length while A and B move to positions A' and B' on circles (blue, yellow) with centers D,C respectively.

4-bar mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, yes, this is what I mean. Can you suggest software that enables its user to animate this mechanism?

Comment: One can set up vectors along the 3 movable links. The shorter link AD rotates full 360 degrees, BC undergoes oscillations. The connecting rod AB has instantaneous rotation around intersection point of AD and BC.